# How to delete "out of stock" item prices in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Deleting WooCommerce out of stock items can't be done using CSS. I would think it could be done by adding a filter, but any more clues? Please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide products that are out of stock by going to the Dashboard -> WooCommerce -> Setting -> Inventory and there is an option called "Out Of Stock Visibility". Tick that box so products with no stock are hidden.